# ng server command opens file "open option menu"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I use 'ng' in the Visual Studio terminal or PowerShell, the following window opens. I don't know how to solve it.

I cannot create components, schematics.

Every time 'ng' is called, the following window pops up:

[image: What appears when I start NG]

@mklement0
I tried reinstalling:
Node.js
PowerShell-7.2.3-win-x64

Problem solved, using :

[image: Get-Command -Type Application ng | Where-Object { $_.Source -match '\ng$' } | Remove-Item]

Comment: Looks like you have a file called 'ng' in your current working directory

Comment: @Theo, in the current directory it wouldn't be a problem (you'd have to invoke it as `.\ng`), but it can cause problems if it's located in one of the directories listed in `$env:PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implication is that **in one of the directories listed in your `$env:PATH` environment variable there is an *extension-less* file literally named `ng`** and that the same directory doesn't also contain an `ng` file *with a filename extension that marks it as an executable*, i.e. one of the extensions listed in `$env:PATHEXT`.

While such a file isn't considered an *executable* file, **PowerShell tries to open it *as a document*** (which is essentially the same as double-clicking a document in File Explorer):

- When extension-less documents are opened, they *always* pop up the GUI dialog shown in your question, because you cannot *persistently* associate an application with them.

To solve your problem you need one to two steps:

- Look for files literally named `ng` (no filename extension) in the directories listed in `$env:PATH` and remove them:

  ```bash
  # Note: This may require running from an ELEVATED session (as admin).
  #       Remove -WhatIf once the output shows the file you want to remove.
  Get-Command -Type Application ng | 
    Where-Object { $_.Source -match '\\ng$' } | 
      Remove-Item -WhatIf
  ```

  - This *may* surface a true `ng` *executable* (a file whose extension is one of the extensions listed in `$env:PATHEXT`, such as `.exe` or `.cmd`) from another directory listed in `$env:PATH`, which the extension-less `ng` file may have shadowed.
- If no such executable surfaces, you'll have to (re)install the desired `ng` application.

Comment: @LuigiCatania, your first screenshot shows the very problem this answer describes. Your second screenshot shows that you mistyped the command that this answer recommends: you're missing a `G` at the start. Note that you'll have to run the command from an _elevated_ session (run as admin), because the offending file is located in `C:\Windows\System32`. Also note that you'll have to remove the `-WhatIf` in order to perform actual deletion.

Comment: Problem solved, it was the fault of the 'whatIf' that I had not removed. I thank you for your patience and time.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @LuigiCatania; my pleasure.