# Powershell not running Nodejs as it should

Tags: node.js, powershell, path

Powershell used to run nodejs like normal before be it using repl or opening in a vscode terminal like I usually do.
Does not anymore. Instead it redirects to the command prompt/opens a new window if I type `node` in Powershell. Any other command and it momentarily opens then closes command prompt in a split second.
It can run some commands like --version if I explicitly give Powershell the full path(C:\Program Files\nodejs) to my node installation but not otherwise. It works fine on Command Prompt though if that explains anything.

I have checked the system Path variables and its there as it should be. I've reinstalled nodejs like thrice, and I updated Powershell but no change.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72331417/45375) applies - analogously - to your situation. If so, we can close your question as a duplicate.